# Sort pages in Flask - TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, flask

I want to be able to sort my posts (pages) based on the date published.
Here's what i do. For each page, I sort them by date and pick the first three.

```
@application.route('/')
def index():
    latest = sorted(pages, reverse=True, key=lambda p: p.meta['date'])
    return render_template('index.html', pages=latest[:3])
```

A simple page (.md) looks like this

```
title: Albums I liked (2015)
date: 2015-12-20
(..other metadata and content)
```

but i get the following error

```
latest = sorted(front, reverse=True,key=lambda p: p.meta['date'])
TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to str
```

How can i sort them properly?

edit: i use https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-FlatPages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error in the line:

```
latest = sorted(front, reverse=True,key=lambda p: p.meta['date'])
```

Because `front` has objects which contains mixed type of data type in `p.meta`. For solving this error, make sure that all dates are either `datetime.date` type or `str` type.

Comment: You are indeed correct, i had a date as follows (2015-07-5)

Answer (score 1):

More likely the data in the .md is string and respectively the date: 2015-12-20 is string. You should convert this date to datetime before sorting in order to achieve the goal. I am not sure if you can just do it in the lambda:

```
from datetime import datetime

latest = sorted(front, reverse=True,key=lambda p: datetime.strptime(p.meta['date'], '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

.. but if this is not possible you should probably load the .md to a list() where the date is also converted to datetime then do the sort. Something like:

```
list = []
for p in data:
    p.meta['date'] = datetime.strptime(p.meta['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    list.append(p)


latest = sorted(list, reverse=True,key=lambda p: p.meta['date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by just converting the date metadata to string. This worked for me smoothly. The new thing here is `str()`

```
latest = sorted(front, reverse=True, key=lambda p: str(p.meta['date']))
```